# How does the Dai stablize?

Tags: economics, dai, stablecoins, defi

I am interested in the Dai stable coin and have seen multiple different explanations of how the coin balances and pegs to the $1. [One](https://youtu.be/J9q8hkyy8oM?t=163) said it was to do with the increase or decrease in interest rates to bring the price up or down(eg. If interest goes up then demand goes down and the price falls and vice versa). The [other](https://youtu.be/wW1IEZeWY4k?t=423) said it was to do with supply and demand change due to people buying cheaper and selling higher for a profit(eg. when the value of dai is higher than dollar people sell for a profit, which increases supply and so the value goes down; when the value is low people buy which drives price up as supply decreases).
Which of these is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the DAI keep its peg to a USD dollar?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59263/how-does-the-dai-keep-its-peg-to-a-usd-dollar)

Comment: Or https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63783/how-does-the-dai-stablecoin-stay-at-1 ?

Comment: Thank you. They both answer my questions, although the second [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63783/how-does-the-dai-stablecoin-stay-at-1)(@eth) helped explain why interest rates aren't used to stabilise the DAI.